# PHP - Laravel - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, utf-8

I'm taking data via ADLDAP, using: https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2 and I have a problem with parsing an image.

[image]

For example, this is an taken image.

When i try to send it via AJAX Call, it returns me an error like:

[image]

I tried to use a specific response format, but, without success.

I've used:

- response()->json($data, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=utf8'), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE),
- json_encode($data);

Comment: Don't send it as JSON.

Comment: Thank you for tip. I've created a new array, put the image there (encoded base64) and sent that new array as response. It's working perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to send an image as json, you have to either reference the path of the image, then populate the src attribute of an img tag, or send it as a base64 encoded image